# Where did the extra quotes come from, or Why is this failing?

Tags: javascript, csv, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with this code shown below in that the .join() isn't working properly due to extra quotes (as far as I can tell anyway). I'm inputting a comma separated list and after the .split(), I'm getting extra quotes around each item in the console for the 'initial' values array like so: ""User"". However, if I console.log the item as I've done with 'test', it comes out like so: "User". That being said, I can't make the evaluation of 'values[i] == "User"', and instead have to write it as I've done in the 'test2' console.log. Normally I would assume that the .split() is the cause, but the documentation for it states that it doesn't change the original string. I'm still pretty much an amateur when it comes to programming, so it's probably staring me in the face. Still, for the life of me, I haven't been able to spot the cause of the problem. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

```
console.log('csv data', csv);
var values = csv.split(',');
console.log('initial', values);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log('test', values[i]);
    console.log('test2', values[i] == '"User"');
    if (values[i] == '"User"') {
        values.splice(i, 1);
        //fails here. .join below fails to execute properly
        return values.join();
        console.log("values recheck", values);
    }
    console.log('testval', values);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just realized that you might need to know, I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE and Chrome to test. I'm not sure if putting this here will make any difference, but here it is anyway.

**EDIT2:**
It was asked for, so here is an example of some CSV data that is in a similar format to what I'm working with:

Cake, Meringue, Cookies, Pudding, Truffles
Chocolate, Lemon, Oatmeal, Banana, Chocolate

Small Edit: I changed the above example to align with proper csv formatting by removing the quotes from the list items. Also, to forestall any questions about it, no, my actual data doesn't have quotes around the list items.

**EDIT3:**
For clarity, here's the code without any of the console.logs:

```
var values = csv.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == '"User"') {
        values.splice(i, 1);
        //fails here. .join below fails to execute properly
        return values.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: The CSV format is more complicated than that, values can contain commas and quotes.  I strongly suggest you use a dedicated CSV library.

Comment: While that may be true, In this case, I can guarantee that each value in my csv input is a word or number without any embellishments.

Comment: What is the CSV data, hard to help without knowing it.

Comment: Sorry, but the CSV data isn't something I'm willing to share. However, I will put together a mockup and post it in an edit.

Comment: The Visual Studio tags should only be used when your question is *about* Visual Studio.  Read the tag description for more information.

Comment: What is your goal with the code? the test and console.log is throwing me off. If your data is multilineal, you should split on \n before ,

Comment: My goal for the code is to grab the value of "User" from a csv input and remove it from that input.